# Overriding Files from third party module

Tags: magento-2.1, module

I'm new to **Magento 2** and still trying to get my head around the folder hierarchy.

If I want a file from my theme to replace a file in a module I am doing the following.

1. For `css`, original file that I want to `override` is here.

   vendor\supplier\module-search-autocomplete\src\SearchAutocomplete\view\frontend\web\css\source\module_cssfile.less

I have copied it to the below location for edit.

```
app\design\frontend\themesupplier\my_theme\module-search-autocomplete\src\SearchAutocomplete\view\frontend\web\css\source\module\_cssfile.less
```

2. php file.

**Original is**:-

```
src\vendor\supplier\module-search-autocomplete\src\SearchAutocomplete\Index\Magento\Catalog\Product.php
```

**Copied to**:-

```
app\design\frontend\themesupplier\my_theme\module-search-autocomplete\src\SearchAutocomplete\Index\Magento\Catalog\Product.php
```

Where did I go wrong ?

I am flushing the cache and also have tried client side compile mode, but changes do not show up.

Clearly I have got the pathing wrong for the copied file, but where ?

Comment: If it's 3rd party module, why don't you modify the file directly?

Comment: I think the Design section does not contains the `.php` file